# Is calling std::min on an empty initializer list (and explicitly specifying the type) undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, undefined-behavior, stl-algorithm

Calling `std::min()` with an empty initializer list usually does not compile (all the question can be stated in the same way for `std::max()`).
This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
   std::cout << std::min({}) << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

With clang gives this error:

```
test.cpp:6:17: error: no matching function for call to 'min'
   std::cout << std::min({}) << "\n";
                ^~~~~~~~
algorithm:2599:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Tp'
min(initializer_list<_Tp> __t)
```

I can see why this case would not be allowed, because it is difficult to agree on a sensible value to return in this case.

However, technically speaking the code does not compile only because the template parameter cannot be deduced. If I force the parameter the code compiles but I get a crash:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

  std::cout << std::min<int>({}) << "\n";

  return 0;
}

$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
$ ./test 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

It seems the crash arises because `std::min()` is implemented in terms of `std::min_element()`, and an empty initializer list results into the dereference of an invalid `end()` iterator.

So is this piece of code undefined behavior under C++11/C++14 ?
Is `std::min()` stated to not compile when called without explicit template parameters?
Is `std::min()` specified to be implemented in terms of `std::min_element()`?

Comment: I didn't expect it to do anything in particular.

Comment: I agree there's no good answer, in principle. I even state it in the question. But since one way of invoking it compiles and another don't, I asked if the one that compiles was indeed specified to be UB.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it's UB. As per C++14 (n4140) 25.4.7/4:

> ```
> template <class T>
> constexpr T min(initializer_list<T> t);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> 4 *Requires:* `T` is `LessThanComparable` and `CopyConstructible` and **`t.size() > 0`**.

(Emphasis mine)

The same wording is present in C++11 as well.

Comment: My bad... I looked at the standard and for some reason I've totally missed the `t.size() > 0` requirement!